# Symfony - ORM Pack conflict with symfony/dependency-injection on installation

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony for the first time and I have created a new project using the following command listed in their documentation:

```bash
symfony new my_project_directory
```

Everything works fine up to this point and the project is created without problems, the problem occurs when I try to install the ORM Pack. I use the following command, that are listed in the Symfony documentation:

```bash
composer require symfony/orm-pack
```

But I have this error:

[image]

```bash
Using version ^2.3 for symfony/orm-pack
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/orm-pack
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "6.1.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/framework-bundle is locked to version v6.1.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - symfony/orm-pack v2.3.0 conflicts with symfony/dependency-injection <6.2.
    - symfony/framework-bundle v6.1.4 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^6.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/dependency-injection[v6.1.3].
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/orm-pack ^2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/orm-pack[v2.3.0].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require symfony/orm-pack:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require symfony/orm-pack:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

My composer.json is the basic one that Symfony installs, without any new libraries added:

```json
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Symfony 6.1 on Windows in the WSL2. What could be the problem? I have only used the steps listed in the Symfony documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I confirmed the same issue on ubuntu.  This sort of thing has cropped up on occasion and is usually fixed in the next release.  You can just use `symfony new --full` or load the individual packages like `composer require doctrine/orm doctrine/doctrine-bundle`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Exactly, as you mentioned, it is possible to install the packages separately and this way it works without any problem. I have also tried installing symfony/orm-pack in version 2.2.0, which is the previous one to the current one, and with this it is also possible to install it.

Thanks again for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Use command:
composer require symfony/orm-pack:^2.1